# Cannot get -fembed-bitcode to work

Tags: xcode7, tvos, swifty-json, bitcode

The current error that I'm getting in Xcode 7.1.1 is:

```
ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because 
'/Users/--/Carthage/Build/tvOS/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON' was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Everyone says to add "-fembed-bitcode" to Other C Flags. I've done that and I'm still getting the same error. I'm not sure if it's in how I'm adding it or what.

I'm currently adding it to Other C Flags > Release > Any tvOS SDK

Any ideas as to why I'm still getting the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you won't be able to re build that framework with bitcode enabled if you don't have the source.

It happened to me that i needed to rebuild from source a few frameworks that luckily were open source.

I looked into SwiftyJSON and it looks like there is already support for bitcode, try updating to the latest version https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Also, by any chance are you getting SwiftyJSON via Carthage? They updated their release with support for bitcode too. https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage